# update random access file in c

Tags: c

I want to do the following in C.

I have a random access data file containing some records.

The records are in the following format:

```
Acct#  First Name     Last Name    Balance
0     ""             ""             0.0
0     ""             ""             0.0
0     ""             ""             0.0
05    Joe             Costanza      0.50
 0     ""             ""             0.0
 0     ""             ""             0.0
 0     ""             ""             0.0
19    Jason           Bourne        58.00
0     ""              ""            0.0
0     ""             ""             0.0
42    Andy            Der          -15.12
0     ""             ""             0.0
0     ""             ""             0.0
```

I want to subtract an amount from balance from all the records that have a non zero account number and write the new updated balance to the file for those records.

This is what I have tried so far to accomplish the above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientData 
{ 
int acctNum;          
char lastName[15];  
char firstName[10]; 
double balance;       
};

void textFile(FILE *readPtr);

int main(void)
{ 
     FILE *cfPtr;

     struct clientData client = {0, "", "", 0.0};

     double serviceCharge = 5.0;

     cfPtr = fopen("credit.dat", "rb+");

     fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);

     client.balance -= serviceCharge;

     fseek(cfPtr,(client.acctNum - 1) * sizeof(struct clientData)
     , SEEK_CUR);

     fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);

     fclose(cfPtr);

     return 0;
}
```

No matter what I try, I just can't write a single updated record back to the file. I have even tried a single record without any while loop or if statement and it still does not work. Can anybody tell me what I am missing.

loop:

```
fread( &client, sizeof( struct clientData ), 1, cfPtr);

while (!feof(cfPtr))
{ 
if ( client.acctNum != 0 )
{
    client.balance -= serviceCharge;
    fseek(cfPtr, (-1 * sizeof(struct clientData)), SEEK_CUR); 

    fwrite( &client, sizeof( struct clientData ), 1, cfPtr);
}

fread( &client, sizeof( struct clientData ), 1, cfPtr);
}
```

Comment: You have `cfPtr` (not declared; opened but not used), `filePtr` (neither declared nor opened, but written to) and `readPtr` (neither declared nor opened, but read from). This code would not compile. Could you please show us the actual code you used, and tell us what it did and what you hoped it would do instead?

Comment: In case the plethora of differently-named file variables indicates that some version of your code tried to open the same file multiple times, reading from one version and writing to another: don't do that, and if you really must do it then flush the file between writing to it and trying to read from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
     while ( !feof( readPtr ) )
     { 
         if ( client.acctNum != 0 )
         {
```

At this point in the code, you haven't *read* anything. Nothing. :)

You've opened the file, you've checked to see if you've reached the end of the file, but there's no code yet to read anything from the file, so your `if` condition is just checking against the initialized structure at the start.

Looping over input typically works best if the input is read at the *top* of the loop. (There are exceptions, but this doesn't look like one of them.)

Try this as a starting point for your loop:

```
while(fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, filePtr)) {
    if (client.acctNum) {
        client.balance -= charge;
        fseek(filePtr, - sizeof(struct clientData), SEEK_CUR);
        if (1 != fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, filePtr))
            perror("Error writing to file");
    }
}
```

The error handling can probably be improved; maybe the whole edit should be aborted. (Mandatory record locking on the file could have *some* writes fail and some writes succeed, but that is pretty unlikely.)

**Update**

Your `fseek()` call is basing the new file position based on multiplying the account number by the size of the `struct clientData`. This works ONLY IF your records are sorted, no numbers are skipped, and it starts at `0` and works up. (Your example input file is not sorted; you even have a record with a `0` account number in the middle of 'valid' records.) So switch to `fseek(..., SEEK_CUR)` instead.

Comment: I hope we learned an important lesson about cobbling together questions based on cut-n-paste :) I found another issue, post updated shortly.

Comment: @user695752, two approaches: **1** to continue using `(client.acctNum - 1)` in your `fseek(3)`: (a) you must be _certain_ that your records are in sorted numerical order, starting at `1` and you cannot skip any numbers in the input file. (b) you must use `SEEK_SET`. **2** Or you can use `SEEK_CUR` without any `client.acctNum` scaling, and just back up over the _one_ record you just read.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the logic errors in your code that @sarnold pointed out, you never `fflush()` your file stream or `fclose()` it. Any updates you make probably remain in the stream buffer and become lost as your program terminates.

Comment: If the program runs to completion, `exit(3)` will flush and close all `stdio(3)` streams. But good advice non-the-less, as errors _do_ happen that prevent full execution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part of the code currently on display:

```
 cfPtr = fopen("credit.dat", "rb+");
 fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
 client.balance -= serviceCharge;
 fseek(cfPtr,(client.acctNum - 1) * sizeof(struct clientData), SEEK_CUR);
 fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
```

I will assume that error checking on the function return values is 'not needed'; it should be there, but it will complicate things slightly.  However, I wouldn't trust myself to write a program without the error checking - too many things can go wrong for my tastes (and bitter experience).

- You read a record at offset 0 into the file.  You then update the balance, seek to a position based on the client account number relative to the current position, and then write the data back.

At another time, we can discuss the wisdom of the binary data format you are using; it is sufficient for the time being.

Here's code that 'works':

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientData 
{ 
    int acctNum;          
    char lastName[15];  
    char firstName[10]; 
    double balance;       
};

static void print_client(struct clientData *data)
{
    printf("%04d %-15s %-15s %6.2f\n", data->acctNum, data->lastName,
           data->firstName, data->balance);
}

int main(void)
{ 
    FILE *cfPtr;
    struct clientData client = {0, "Me", "Mine", 50.0};
    double serviceCharge = 5.0;

    /* Initialize */
    cfPtr = fopen("credit.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr);

    /* Update */
    cfPtr = fopen("credit.dat", "rb+");
    fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
    print_client(&client);
    client.balance -= serviceCharge;
    fseek(cfPtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr);

    /* Validate */
    cfPtr = fopen("credit.dat", "rb");
    fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr);
    print_client(&client);

    return 0;
}
```

---

This works too...it doesn't skip 0 client IDs because it doesn't generate any.  But you can deal with that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientData 
{ 
    int acctNum;          
    char lastName[15];  
    char firstName[10]; 
    double balance;       
};

static void print_client(const struct clientData *data)
{
    printf("%04d %-15s %-15s %6.2f\n", data->acctNum, data->lastName,
           data->firstName, data->balance);
}

/* Initialize file */
static void init_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen(filename, "wb");
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        struct clientData client = { i, "", "", i * 50.0};
        sprintf(client.lastName, "Me (%d)", i);
        sprintf(client.firstName, "Mine (%d)", i);
        fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
    }
    fclose(cfPtr);
}

static void print_file(const char *filename)
{
    struct clientData client;
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    while (fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr) == 1)
        print_client(&client);
    fclose(cfPtr);
}

int main(void)
{ 
    FILE *cfPtr;
    double serviceCharge = 5.0;
    const char *filename = "credit.dat";
    struct clientData client;

    init_file(filename);
    printf("Post-initialization: %s\n", filename);
    print_file(filename);

    /* Update */
    cfPtr = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    while (fread(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr) == 1)
    {
        client.balance -= serviceCharge;
        fseek(cfPtr, -1 * (long)sizeof(struct clientData), SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&client, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, cfPtr);
        fseek(cfPtr, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(cfPtr);

    printf("Post-update: %s\n", filename);
    print_file(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

See also the comments...

Comment: @user695752: We try not to spoon feed people too much.  You can write a function with a loop to create a number of records in place of the one record my code writes -- you have to have a way to create the file before you can update it.  You'll need to alter the record numbering to match your convention that record N is at offset (N-1)×record_size.  Then you can seek and read, and seek and write to find records.  Then you can write a function with a loop to dump the contents of the file.  Maybe you prompt for the record number(s) to be updated in a loop.  Etc.

Comment: @user695752: According to the C standard, you must do a seek between each switch between reading and writing; you only do one seek, not two. You should also forget about `feof()`; you do not normally use it in C -- it suggests a Pascal background. Check the result of `fread()` which tells you whether you reached EOF or not (or encountered some I/O error).  That also means you don't have to write the `fread()` statement twice - you write it once in the main loop condition in place of `feof()`.